# How to add horizontal scroll to a flex container in a Bootstrap navigation menu?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap navigation menu with a flex container (). I want to enable horizontal scrolling for the menu items when they exceed the container width. I have applied the following CSS style to the container:

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, the horizontal scroll doesn't seem to be working as expected. The menu items still wrap to the next line instead of providing a horizontal scroll.

Here is the HTML code for my navigation menu:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills tab-listing" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4<li>
</ul>
```

Comment: flex-wrap: nowrap;
This fill fix it

Answer (score 0):

Set `flex-wrap: nowrap` to prevent menu items from wrapping to the next line, and use `overflow-x:` auto to enable horizontal scrolling if the item exceeds the width of the container.

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution,
But I have tried this already, when i apply flex-wrap: nowrap my entire screen gets a horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Give a specific width to those you want to show the navigation menu on the entire screen, and then get horizontal scrolling as per your requirement.

```css
.nav {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 500px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills tab-listing" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4<li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8<li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12<li>
    <li>Item 13</li>
    <li>Item 14</li>
    <li>Item 15</li>
</ul>
```

Here you can change the value for the `max-width` as per your requirement to show menu on the screen and other is scroll.